# How does Firefox resolve CSS font-family to local font

Tags: firefox, fonts

Given a CSS font-family such as "font-family: courier", how does Firefox decide which font to use?

The reason I ask is because I installed Courier Prime in my home directory.  I'd like to see Courier Prime in my browser whenever a web page specifies "font-family: courier", instead of Nimbus Mono L.  I've already tried using Font-Manager to disable Nimbus Mono L, but that causes Firefox to substitute FreeSans, which is not a Courier font at all.

Here's a page that uses "font-family: courier": http://bathroomepiphanies.com/firmwares/

Interestingly Chromium selects Liberation Mono.  Not strictly a Courier font, but a worthy monospaced font.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the default fonts used by Firefox in Firefox' own preferences. Open them from the **Edit → Preferences** menu or by typing `about:preferences` into the address bar.

You should be able to find a **Language and Appearance** section under **General** preferences:

[image: Language and Appearance]

The default font dropdown here specifies what font is used when the website does not specify any font family at all.

If you want to change which fonts are used if only a generic font family like `serif`, `sans-serif` or `monospace` is specified in the website's style sheets, you click on **Advanced...** to open the dialogue below:

[image: Advanced Fonts Settings]

<sub>The actual look and layout of these preferences may change depending on your used Firefox version and theme.</sub>